# How do I get the listview id using page id in another page in jquery mobile?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I am working on jquery mobile. How do I get the id of listview which is placed in page 2? I need to work with listview click event in page 1.

Comment: Hi, it's very difficult to work out what you're asking here - can you be more specific? Post code? Things that you've tried? As it stands this isn't really an answerable question.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)